# Truffle migrate does not run 2_deploy_contracts.js

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, infura

I am having problems with `truffle migrate` on the default Truffle project and using Infura as the provider.

**Steps to reproduce problem**

1. `truffle init`
2. `npm install ethereumjs-wallet bip39 web3-provider-engine@8.6.1 web3@0.18.4 zeppelin-solidity --save`
3. Edit `truffle.js` to use deterministic wallet and infura provider. (Code below)
4. `truffle compile`
5. `truffle migrate --network rinkeby`

However running `truffle migrate --network rinkeby` does only a partial migrate. It does not go on to migrate `2_deploy_contracts.js`.

```
$ truffle migrate --network rinkeby
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0xf7a1eea43cfe61d59f55a3f5ce8b1c33bc9d5b37c2486ebdc83fdf4d1ba03041
$
```

Anyone knows what might be the problem?

---

Using:

- Truffle v3.4.9 (core: 3.4.8)
- Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)

---

**truffle.js**

```
var bip39 = require("bip39");
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');
var ProviderEngine = require("web3-provider-engine");
var WalletSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/wallet.js');
var Web3Subprovider = require("web3-provider-engine/subproviders/web3.js");
var Web3 = require("web3");

// Get our mnemonic and create an hdwallet
var mnemonic = "couch solve unique spirit wine fine occur rhythm foot feature glory away";
var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));

// Get the first account using the standard hd path.
var wallet_hdpath = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/";
var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(wallet_hdpath + "0").getWallet();
var address = "0x" + wallet.getAddress().toString("hex");

var providerUrl = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/somekey";
var engine = new ProviderEngine();
engine.addProvider(new WalletSubprovider(wallet, {}));
engine.addProvider(new Web3Subprovider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerUrl)));
engine.start(); // Required by the provider engine.


module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },

    rinkeby: {
        network_id: 4,
        provider: engine,
        from: address
    }
  }
};
```

---

Here's the output of `truffle migrate --network rinkeby --verbose-rpc`

```
Using network 'rinkeby'.

  Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
     .> {
     .>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     .>   "id": 1,
     .>   "method": "eth_accounts",
     .>   "params": []
     .> }
   .<   {
   .<     "id": 1,
   .<     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   .<     "result": [
   .<       "0xcede48d8ac162d1b08ed9419010de3c99f2cfdd6"
   .<     ]
   .<   }
     .> {
     .>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     .>   "id": 2,
     .>   "method": "net_version",
     .>   "params": []
     .> }
   .<   {
   .<     "id": 2,
   .<     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   .<     "result": "4"
   .<   }
    Deploying Migrations...
     .> {
     .>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     .>   "id": 3,
     .>   "method": "net_version",
     .>   "params": []
     .> }
   .<   {
   .<     "id": 3,
   .<     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   .<     "result": "4"
   .<   }
     .> {
     .>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     .>   "id": 4,
     .>   "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
     .>   "params": [
     .>     {
     .>       "from": "0xcede48d8ac162d1b08ed9419010de3c99f2cfdd6",
     .>       "gas": "0x47e7c4",
     .>       "gasPrice": "0x174876e800",
     .>       "data": "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"
     .>     }
     .>   ]
     .> }
     .> {
     .>   "id": 1507552744042366,
     .>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     .>   "params": [
     .>     "0xcede48d8ac162d1b08ed9419010de3c99f2cfdd6",
     .>     "pending"
     .>   ],
     .>   "method": "eth_getTransactionCount"
     .> }
   .<   {
   .<     "id": 1507552744042366,
   .<     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   .<     "result": "0x13"
   .<   }
     .> {
     .>   "id": 1507552744515044,
     .>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     .>   "params": [
     .>     "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"
     .>   ],
     .>   "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction"
     .> }
   .<   {
   .<     "id": 1507552744515044,
   .<     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   .<     "result": "0xf2b4e82e4a806ad1adcd8ff4e6d5cad05ee99302a2265810e3de04fd3a652c33"
   .<   }
   .<   {
   .<     "id": 4,
   .<     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   .<     "result": "0xf2b4e82e4a806ad1adcd8ff4e6d5cad05ee99302a2265810e3de04fd3a652c33"
   .<   }
    ... 0xf2b4e82e4a806ad1adcd8ff4e6d5cad05ee99302a2265810e3de04fd3a652c33
     .> {
     .>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     .>   "id": 5,
     .>   "method": "eth_newBlockFilter",
     .>   "params": []
     .> }
```

Comment: What happens after this?
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0xf7a1eea43cfe61d59f55a3f5ce8b1c33bc9d5b37c2486ebdc83fdf4d1ba03041

Comment: @pabloruiz55 I end up back in bash. It does not proceed to deploy `2_deploy_contracts.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: You can replace the code provided by the Infura / Truffle tutorial as follows, which is extremely shorter and easier to read/modify.

You can change all the code above for the two lines below to make it much easier.

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = "word1 word2 word3 etc";
```

Install truffle-hdwallet-provider package.

```
$ npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider
```

Then:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/wefbowufweufbweu"), // The actual api key infura gave you
      network_id: '3'
    }
  }
}
```

*This example uses Ropsten, but changing it to Rinkeby should be trivial, just make sure you are using the url Infura gave you with the correct api key and network_id 4 instead of 3*

Comment: What about `2_deploy_contracts.js`? Truffle seems to quit after deploying `1_initial_migration.js`

Comment: Try using the --reset flag to see if it makes a difference. What puzzles me is that the contract did get deployed as you can see on Etherscan.
truffle compile --network rinkeby --reset
truffle migrate --network rinkeby --reset

Comment: Running with the `--reset` flag did not change anything... Are u on an older version of truffle for this to work? On testrpc, truffle proceeds to deploy `2_deploy_contracts.js`

Comment: Just updated this answer. Hope it helps. @Nyxynyx

Comment: It works when using `truffle-hdwallet-provider`!! Not sure why the previous code straight from Infura's website didnt work...

Comment: Thanks. I did use a fake mnemonic phrase and fake Infura access token in the question.